# Problema consumiendo api AXIOS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, axios

No logro hacer que axios me envíe la data como yo necesito.

Así me la envía axios `{ '{nickname:"darkoz",password:"12345"}': '' }`

Así la envió con postman`{ nickname: 'darkoz', password: '12345' }`

¿Cómo podría hacerlo así?

```js
      const requestBody = {
            nickname:  this.nickname.current.value,
            password: this.pwd.current.value
          }
          
          const config = {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
          }
          
          axios.post(API+'/login', requestBody, config)
            .then( (res) => {

                /* envia toda la data al componente padre */
                this.props.login(res)                
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.mostrarError(error)
            });
```

Comment: parece que el problema es la configuracion (config), pues al quitar eso, cambia la respuesta.

Comment: Se ejecuta el then o el catch en tu consulta?

Comment: Bienvenido @Daniel Nava, he estado revisando la doc de 'Axios' y te especifica como usarlo si usas 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. Te dejo el enlace para que puedas echarle un vistazo y probar:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, por defecto Axios envía la información en formato JSON, para enviarlo en el formato application/x-www-form-urlencoded debes usar alguna de estas soluciones:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);





var qs = require('qs');
axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
```